# How can i retrieve Session ID from particular Session Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to retrieve a Session ID for a particular Session variable in C#.

```
Session["OrderDetailList"] = OrderDetailsList;
```

What i am trying is that I want to save List in a session and also want to store its Session ID in cookie.

Also When I retrieve Session ID from cookie then i can able to save the value of Session variable having Session ID retrieve from cookie.

How can we do that?

Comment: A SessionID is for an entire Session and not for a specific session variable. In your example above, the list itself doesnt have any unique session ID. The session ID is unique and shared for ALL values stored in that particular session. Also, can you clarify your 2nd last sentence - atleast I find it to be particularly confusing

Comment: my 2nd last sentence mean i have to retrieve Session ID from Cookie and from that Session ID we can fetch Session Value

Comment: OK. I think how to retrieve SessionID is already answered in both KnowledgeSeeker as well as AVD's answer below. ALso, to get a session value eg: OrderDetailsList, you dont need to use the SessionID at all. Just doing Session["OrderDetailList"] is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/ In a user control or page
string sessionId = this.Session.SessionID; 

// In a normal class, running in a asp.net app.
string sessionId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
```

Beside this i would also recommend to checkout this good article

[Exploring Session in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net)

Comment: ok How can I find session Variables from Session Id. Is it Possible to get session variables from session IDs

Comment: You can do a global search using regular expression

Something like this may do the trick

`(?:Session\[.+\]\s*=|Session.Add)`

First part cover session variables created by assigment: Session["MyVarName"] = myValue

Second part cover session variables created using Add method: `Session.Add("MyVarName", myValue)`

Answer (score 1):

> How can I retrieve Session ID from particular Session Variable?

No. You cannot. Read [MSDN document for more info.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

By default Session uses *cookie* to save `SessionID` and you can obtain SessionID via 
`Session` object in server-code.